# factory_bot / factory_girl syntax for adding a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following model:

```
class SecondaryIabCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sites, foreign_key: :secondary_category_id
  belongs_to :primary_iab_category
end
```

and the following factories with the problem with a comment:

```
  factory :primary_category, class: PrimaryIabCategory do
    name 'Arts & Entertainment - yaddah'
    value 'IAB1-some'
  end

  factory :another_primary_category, class: PrimaryIabCategory do
    name 'Games are cool! - dabbah'
    value 'IAB1-other'
  end

  factory :secondary_category, class:  SecondaryIabCategory do
    # here is the problem - what's the correct syntax?
    primary_iab_category another_primary_category
    name 'Test Secondary Cat'
    value 'xxyy'
  end
```

I get the error msg:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `another_primary_category=' for #<SecondaryIabCategory:0x00007f925c64e0d8>
```

I haven't used FactoryBot/Girl for several months so not sure what the syntax for this would be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
factory :secondary_category, class:  SecondaryIabCategory do
  association :primary_iab_category, factory: :another_primary_category
  name 'Test Secondary Cat'
  value 'xxyy'
end
```

The [rubydoc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations) is pretty details

Comment: thx - yeah, probably should be on the getting started page too.